# code name one error:411 length required

Tags: java, codenameone

Hi guys I have a problem in `codename` one api sms 
when I push the button he show me this error (error:411 length required)

```
btsms.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        // String myURL = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=*****&api_secret=*****&to=*****" + "&from=*****&text=*****";
        String myURL = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json?api_key=d5b95eee&api_secret=93a8c398b48c63bf&to=21625308299&from=NEXMO&text=reservation_annulée";

        ConnectionRequest cntRqst = new ConnectionRequest() {
            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream in) throws IOException {

            }

            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
                Dialog.show("SMS", "sms successfully sent", "OK", null);
            }
        };
        cntRqst.setUrl(myURL);
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(cntRqst);
    }
});
```

Can you help me please thanks :)

Comment: So, what happened when you added a length parameter?

Comment: horrible idea to include apikey in the code, i would suggest you ask for a new one as someone can steal your credentials.

Comment: it seems the error returned from the external API, read their docs on the required call

Comment: how can i add length parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

Before I begin you do know there is a [Twilio SMS callback library](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-activation-ui-builder-pattern.html) in Codename One right?

You are sending a post call with a URL that's constructed for GET. A minimal fix would be:

```
cntRqst.setPost(false);
```

However, I would personally write it as:

```
ConnectionRequest cntRqst = new ConnectionRequest("https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json", false) {
    // ...
};


cntRqst.addArgument("api_key", API_KEY);
cntRqst.addArgument("api_secret", API_SECRET);
cntRqst.addArgument("to", "21625308299");
cntRqst.addArgument("from", "NEXMO");
cntRqst.addArgument("text", "reservation_annulée");
```

The advantage of this is the text is implicitly encoded and you can dynamically switch between GET/POST easily.

There is also the newer REST API (assuming result is JSON):

```
Response<Map> response = Rest.get("https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json").
   queryParam("api_key", API_KEY).
   queryParam("api_secret", API_SECRET).
   queryParam("to", "21625308299").
   queryParam("from", "NEXMO").
   queryParam("text", "reservation_annulée").
   getAsJsonMap();
```